# "sprung for action"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-meaning

From [the 2012 movie *Gambit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_(2012_film))

> There are moments in a life that define a man. This was Mr Deane's. He was **sprung for action** and yet perfectly capable of blowing it completely.

My understanding of the line is that Mr. Deane stayed ready for action. However, I can't really get that from dictionary definitions of the verb "spring". Having plowed through the most exhaustive of dictionaries--the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), Wiktionary, Merriam-Webster-- I am still not sure if this usage has been defined and if there is a corresponding dictionary entry at all. And yes, I have checked Cambridge, Lexico (revamped ODO), Collins, and a few others. I thought *to cause a mechanism to work*, as in *spring a trap* might be close, but still sounds off the mark. This usage also seems analogous to a wind-up toy ready for action.

Here are some other examples:

> Scalia is described as “perpetually **sprung for action**” during oral arguments, rocking in his chair “like a restless kid waiting for his turn at the blackboard.” ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=1PW0pzLlL2cC&pg=PA19&dq=%22sprung%20for%20action%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj44-CgoP7iAhVvdt8KHSJaCekQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22sprung%20for%20action%22&f=false))
>
> Her right hand holds a cross-bow, **sprung for action** and armed with an arrow, pointing to the ground. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=ckNdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA242&dq=%22sprung%20for%20action%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj44-CgoP7iAhVvdt8KHSJaCekQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=%22sprung%20for%20action%22&f=false))
>
> ...chart-table, which was designed to be collapsible, and in rough weather invariably did just that, was an open, man-sized hole from which a ten-rung ladder led down to the mess deck: he described it as 'a vicious mantrap **sprung for action**'. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=3b3qTQh5XOwC&pg=PA171&dq=%22sprung%20for%20action%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj44-CgoP7iAhVvdt8KHSJaCekQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=%22sprung%20for%20action%22&f=false))

My question is: What exactly does "spring" mean in "spring for action"? Please point to a dictionary instead of pulling something out of a hat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase isn't "spring for action" it's only "sprung for action." As you guessed, it essentially means ready for action--coiled with tension, like a compressed spring that is full of potential energy and ready to be sprung.

It's most closely associated with verb definitions 1.6, 3.8, and 13.8-13.9 at [this wiktionary link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spring#Verb), especially the last two, which are "to act as a spring" or "to equip with springs." In 1.6, you see the meaning is associated with the motion of a bow, which "when bent, springs back by its elastic power."

So it's quite literal in the cross-bow example: the bow is sprung (or curved with tension) and armed, ready for action. It's more metaphorical when applied to a person, as in the Scalia example.

Comment: Another example that may help clarify: [pocket sprung mattresses](https://www.mattressonline.co.uk/advice/what-is-pocket-sprung-mattress)